# JavaScript regular expression calculating wrongly

Tags: javascript, regex

I m using a local JavaScript executed on Chrome browser.
I really don't understand why this is providing the wrong result:

Script:

```
var str = "hello 1 test test hello 2";
var patt = /(hello \S+)/g;
var res = str.split(patt);
//var res = str.search(patt);
if(res!=null) {
    for(var i=0;i<res.length;i++) console.log(i+res[i]);
}
```

Output:

```
0
1hello 1
2 test test 
3hello 2
4
```

Expected Result:

```
0hello 1
1hello 2
```

What am I doing wrong?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're looking for matches rather than splitting the string

Use `str.match(patt)`

[str.match](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)

Instead, your answer is splitting the string twice, as your regular expression matches in two places. Splitting a string by regex gives 3 parts. Before the match, the match, and after the match.

Your string has matched twice. Meaning that this process has happened twice, resulting in 5 parts, the result shown (two parts are empty).

Comment: This it is! Thanks mate! I will mark the answer as completed after the 8 minutes are over

Comment: Thanks. If you're using regex a lot, a tool that I often use, and find very useful is [Regexr](http://www.regexr.com)

Answer (score 0):

## Match approach

With `match`, it is much simpler, just use `/hello\s+\S+/g`:

```js
var str = "hello 1 test test hello 2";
var patt = /hello\s+\S+/g;
var res = str.match(patt);
if(res!=null) {
    for(var i=0;i<res.length;i++)
        console.log(i+res[i]);
      }
```

Note that you do not need any capturing groups in this case as you are not using the captured text, you need the whole matched text. Besides, `\s+` will match any whitespace there can be between `hello` and a sequence of non-whitespace characters.

## Split approach

You need to match the rest of the string that is after `hello \S+` and remove blank entries before outputting them:

```js
var str = "hello 1 test test hello 2";
var patt = /(hello \S+).*?(?=$|hello \S)/g;
var res = str.split(patt);
//var res = str.search(patt);
if(res!=null) {
   res = res.filter(Boolean);
    for(var i=0;i<res.length;i++)
      if (res[i]) {
        console.log(i+res[i]);
      }
}
```

Result:

```
0hello 1
js:21 1hello 2
```

The regex - `(hello \S+).*?(?=$|hello \S)` - matches and captures the `hello` + a sequence of non-whitespace symbols, and then any characters but a newline up to the end of string or next `hello` + non-whitespace characters.

I have used `res.filter(Boolean);` to remove empty elements in the resulting array (that almost always are present when splitting with regex).

Comment: what black magic is this? why is it so different to the normal reg ex? https://regex101.com/r/iP8lV6/18

Comment: Could you clarify what "black magic" do you see here? I have a normal regex. I just assumed you want to use a `split` here. With `match`, it is much simpler, sure.

Comment: I added a `match` approach with removed capturing group from the regex.

Answer (score 0):

You used [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split), then you have an array with all values before and after each match of `/(hello \S+)/g`.

You want to use [`match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match):

```
"hello 1 test test hello 2".match(/(hello \S+)/g);
// ["hello 1", "hello 2"]
```

Answer (score 0):

`split` ... splits the string.

Just as splitting `x,y,z` by `/(,)/` will give you `["x", ",", "y", ",", "z"]`, you get the result seen here.

What you wanted to do was iterate over the matches:

```
str.match(/(hello \S+)/g)
```